# .net core replacement for BlobStorageService

Tags: c#, .net

i have tried using blob storage service but since i have used .net core and not 
framework its not working and its telling me that blob storage service is not there in your package.Kindly help me in resolving the issue.

```
    BlobStorageService blobStorageService = new BlobStorageService();
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Retrieve(string date)
    {
        date = "2018/07/25";
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobStorageService.GetCloudBlobContainer();
        string blobPath = $"QuickServiceWebApp006/{date}";
        CloudBlobDirectory directory = blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(blobPath);
        List<string> blobs = new List<string>();
        //(prefix: "Folder1/Subfolder1", useFlatBlobListing: true)
        foreach (var blobItem in directory.ListBlobs(true))
        {
            //blobs.Add(blobItem.ToString());
            string[] pathArray = blobItem.Uri.ToString().Split('/');
            string blobName = $"{pathArray[pathArray.Length - 2] }/{ pathArray[pathArray.Length - 1]}";
            CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($"{blobPath}/{blobName}");
            string text;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //downloads blob's content to a stream
                blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);

                //puts the byte arrays to a string
                text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

            }

            return View("Retrieve");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=windows

Comment: I see you are missing `await` before `blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a reference to [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob)

Then, in your code, you'll need to change:

```
blobContainer = blobStorageService.GetCloudBlobContainer();
```

To something along the lines of:

```
CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(
    uri, new StorageCredentials(accountName, key));
```

Comment: i have tried this..but its not coming..i have installed all the packages and added the reference but still its not coming...Since i have done my project in .net core and not .net framework , is there any replacement for the blog storage service in that?

Comment: That is for .net core
When you say "not coming" what do you mean?

Comment: THANKYOU NOW ITS WORKING